# File download from database not working

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've inherited this site and having issues with file downloads. Files such as .pdf, .doxs, .txt are saved in Sql as image. A datalist controls is used with a `a href` controls to view it/downloaded it but it's not working. And I realize that `a href` control is not a proper control to use but not sure what control to use.

Here is the aspx markup:

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataList2" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" DataKeyField="fileId">
   <ItemTemplate>
     <a href='<%# "~/UserControls/FileFetch.ashx?fileId=" + Convert.ToString(Eval("fileId")) %>' target="_blank">
       <%# Convert.ToString(Eval("fileName"))%></a>
   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ClubSiteDB %>"
  SelectCommand="SELECT [fileId], [fileName], [postedBy] FROM [FilesLibrary]">                
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

A helper file called FileFetch.ashx is used to get the file:

```
<%@ WebHandler Language="C#" Class="FileFetch" %>

using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;
using System.IO;

public class FileFetch : IHttpHandler
{
    const int BUFFERSIZE = 1024;

    public bool IsReusable
    {
       get
       {
           return true;
       }
    }

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
       HttpResponse response = context.Response;
       HttpRequest request = context.Request;
       response.ContentType = "response.ContentType";
       response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Public);
       response.BufferOutput = false;
       writeSingleImage(Convert.ToInt32(request.QueryString["fileId"]), response.OutputStream);
       response.End();
    }

    public void writeSingleImage(int fileId, Stream output)
    {
        string cxnstr = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ClubSiteDB"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(cxnstr);
        string query;
        query = "SELECT fileData FROM dbo.FilesLibrary where fileId=@fileId";

        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
        SqlParameter param0 = new SqlParameter("@fileId", SqlDbType.Int);
        param0.Value = fileId;
        command.Parameters.Add(param0);
        connection.Open();

        byte[] d = ((byte[])(command.ExecuteScalar()));
        output.Write(d, 0, d.Length);
        connection.Close();
   }
```

}

Comment: What's the error? Have you tracked down what line it's failing on?

Comment: I get: `
The resource cannot be found. 
  Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly. 

 Requested URL: /Test/~/UserControls/FileFetch.ashx`. But the database has the record with the particular id. Also debugger never goes into the FileFetch.ashx file.

Comment: Ahh, well the problem isn't the href control, it's that it can't find the generic handler (ashx file). From the looks of it it's probably a configuration issue in IIS?

Comment: I'm just using the ASP.net development server with VS2012.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to take a stab at this and say you need to change your `Anchor` tag to be the following:

```
<a href='<%# Page.ResolveUrl("~/UserControls/FileFetch.ashx?fileId=" + Convert.ToString(Eval("fileId"))) %>' target="_blank">
```

The MSDN link to the `Page.ResolveUrl` method is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.resolveurl.aspx). Page inherits from Control, hence why the link refers to Control.ResolveUrl.

I've just seen that another alternative is to add `runat="server"` to the `Anchor` tag to turn it into a server control.

Comment: Well, this went a little further and got actual data, unfortunately what was displayed, was the jibrish code of the .pdf rather then the properly rendered pdf file.

Comment: Well yes, that's true.

Comment: Ok, have you tried both solutions (i.e. also adding the runat=server)?